# WebService DataSet Deserialization Error - diffgram

Tags: .net, web-services

I am using a third party web service that I have no control over. This web service returns a DataSet from one of its methods.

When I call the method, I get an error: {"There is an error in XML document (1, 34926)."}. The inner exception is "Column requires a valid DataType".

I have used fiddler to actually look at the XML that is being returned. The XML has a xs:schema section that looks fine. However, this is followed by diffgr:diffgram section:

```
    <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    ....
    </xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    ....
```

This section is not mentioned in the schema so I can't see how it is a valid XML document!

To get round this issue can I override the deserialization process to strip this diffgram section out or something?

Comment: You are learning why not to return `DataSet` from a web service. Good luck.

Comment: In the end I wrote my own service rather than using the 3rd party service and I certainly didn't use DataSets :)

Comment: One additional item is that the normal out-of-the-box `DataSet` can't have the DiffGram stripped out, because it is required to keep the integrity of the DataSet. If you use typed DataSet, because the schema is included in a separate .xsd, it can be excluded. But yes - DataSet's are not recommended for Web service calls.